# Short clauses taking a comma (he's and she's) style or rule

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, style

So I read that short clauses taking commas is a style choice but preferably the use of a semi-colon, full stop, conjunction  is accurate. As in:

> Experts teach; peers comfort (or and).

But if for example you had:

> Donna's good at football, she's always scoring goals.

or:

Joey's so good at football, he's talented.

Or shorter:

> Donna's great, she's a star.

Do these fall into the same rules? You see this usage informally from time to time.

Can *he's* and *she's* not act as a conjunction in these instances?

Answer (score 1):

You do often see this, but it is considered a flaw in formal writing (called a comma splice).

You should use a semicolon to separate grammatically independent, but related clauses:

> Donna's great; she's a star!
>
> Donna's so good a football; she's always scoring goals.

The word "she's" cannot act as a conjunction. (If "she's" was a conjunction, what is the subject of "she's always scoring goals"?)

In informal writing, using comma splices are fairly common, and generally overlooked.

Comment: What is the term for words like 'it' that bridge sentences but aren't conjunctions for independent clauses.  They 'act' as conjunctions connecting dependent clauses.

Comment: The don't act as bridges or conjucntions. They are pronouns, functioning as the subject of clauses. They don't connect dependent clauses. The start a new independent clause.

Comment: I don't really understand the comment, but I think you can ask it as a new question rather than as a comment.

Comment: Donna's great; she's a star vs If Donna is so great, why isn't she a star.

Comment: The hour was late as she closed her eyes and began to drift to sleep, drifting on a sea of possibilities.   (what do we call the contrast in these two subordinate/opening clauses) This example and the 'If Donna is so great'.

Comment: Please ask a new question rather than commenting.